# Issues using Swift Package Manager and CocoaPods in single project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

We've decided to use SPM for our new internal frameworks. Our app has many dependencies (for the moment) on some CocoaPods. So, I figured adding SPM would be easy enough.

I created a local Swift Package and linked it against the project. All good, until I import the new Package into a `Swift` file

Once I do that and try build on the iOS simulator, I am faced with the following compiler error:

`could not find module 'CoreKit' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator';`

I am able to build to a device, no problem. Just not the simulator.

We faced a similar issue for Pods; which resulted us adding the following in our `Podfile`

```
 installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
```

We had to do this, since we use M1 Machines.

I have tried the following:

- Removing `arm64` from the `Excluded Architectures`
- Setting `Build Active Archives only` to `YES/NO`
- Adding `x86_64` to `Architectures`
- Removing the config for `arm64` from the `Podfile`

Open to any suggestions on how we can resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Neither package manager supports working with the other. I recommend choosing one.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, that’s incorrect. They can and do work in the same project. They have nothing to do with each other. I know of another project where they have both working together.

Comment: To be clear, it's possible to make work when requested dependencies and sub-dependencies are non-intersecting sets - but as soon as there is a common shared dependency, integrating will be painful.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in our project, Googles ARCore still doesn't have SPM support, so we can't remove cocoapods. @RobertJ.Clegg did you make any progress since march on this?
(also created an issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11416 )

Comment: @Bersaelor - Could not find a solution. Had to give up and stick with Cocopods, unfortunately.